# Transform incoming response with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

Hi i try to create a node app that runs locally and for example looks for a request to an url e.g. www.google.nl and return a different response, like you can do with Charles.

I managed to intercept incoming connections with [node-pcap](https://github.com/mranney/node_pcap) but with this lib i can't manipulate the response only read it.
Than i was looking into [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) even reverse (but correct me if i'm wrong) this is also not what i'm looking for.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thx!

Comment: Do you want to direct requests to different web servers or to different pages?

Comment: I would like to transform a json response coming from an external source with an other json.